# Common Lisp: function A passes a function to B which passes it to C which invokes the function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

The following `helloworld` function simply outputs Hello, world

```
(defun helloworld ()
    (format t "Hello, world"))
```

I created a function `A` that passes `helloworld` to function `B`:

```
(defun A ()
    (B #'helloworld))
```

Function `B` then passes the function to function C:

```
(defun B (fn)
    (C #'fn))
```

Function `C` then invokes the function (i.e., it invokes `helloworld`):

```
(defun C (fn)
    (funcall fn))
```

When I run the program:

```
(A)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in FUNCTION [or a callee]: The function FN is undefined.
```

Why?

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I just discovered the error of my ways.

Function `A` is passing the `helloworld` function to `B`:

```
(defun A ()
    (B #'helloworld))
```

So `B` *has* the function and so `B` has no need to use `#'` (or `function`) to *get* the function. Thus, `B` simply needs to pass the function to `C`:

```
(defun B (fn)
    (C fn))
```

Likewise, C *has* the function and so it simply needs to call the function:

```
(defun C (fn)
    (funcall fn))
```

TaDa! That works!

Comment: You should probably accept one of the answer (either yours or the other).

Answer (score 7):

```
(C #'fn)
```

This looks for a function called `fn` created with things like `defun`, `labels`, `flet` etc. You have a variable which contains a function, so you should just forward it on to `C` rather than looking up its name:

```
(defun B (fn)
    (C fn))
;     ^^ no #'
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/BctuUl)

Comment: ideone seems to use Flash. Make sure that you have deinstalled Flash. There are constant security problems with Flash and just now an unpatched security problem is known: http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/10/new-zero-day-exploit-hits-fully-patched-adobe-flash/